# Is there 'not promise' type in typescipt?

Tags: typescript, types, promise, void

I'm writing TypeScript and want to create something like `Exclude<void, Promise<void>>`, which allows `void` but not allow `Promise<void>`.

```
type A = (a: number) => Promise<void>
type B = (a: number) => void

declare let a: A
declare let b: B
// it does not cause type error
b = a

// what i want to do...
// but it is identical to B
type C = (a: number) => Exclude<void, Promise<void>>
```

However, `Exclude<void,Promise<void>>` seems to be identical to `void`.

Is there some ways to create type like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void) puts it:

> `void` is a little like the opposite of `any`: the absence of having any type at all.

Since it's the absence of having any type, it makes no sense to *exclude* something from it.

The reason why you can assign type `A` to type `B` is that, simply put, any function can be `void` if you just ignore the return type. Because what a return type of `void` essentially means is that you can't use the return value. And this property is compatible with any function, you just have to ignore whatever it is returning.

This doesn't only affect `Promise<void>` but all return types:

```js
declare let voidFunction: (a: number) => void;
declare let promiseFunction: (a: number) => Promise<void>;
declare let numberFunction: (a: number) => number;
declare let stringFunction: (a: number) => string;
declare let undefinedFunction: (a: number) => undefined;

voidFunction = promiseFunction; // no error
voidFunction = numberFunction; // no error
voidFunction = stringFunction; // no error
voidFunction = undefinedFunction; // no error
```

However, note that the opposite isn't true:

```js
promiseFunction = voidFunction; // error
numberFunction = voidFunction; // error
stringFunction = voidFunction; // error
undefinedFunction = voidFunction; // error
```

---

I think a better solution for your case would actually be to use `undefined` as return type instead of `void`:

```js
undefinedFunction = promiseFunction; // error
undefinedFunction = numberFunction; // error
undefinedFunction = stringFunction; // error
```

However the issue with this is that when you declare a function with return type `undefined` you actually need to have a `return undefined;` statement, which you probably don't want.

To solve this, I believe `undefined | void` would be a good compromise for a return type:

```js
declare let undefinedVoidFunction: (a: number) => undefined | void;

undefinedVoidFunction = promiseFunction // error
undefinedVoidFunction = numberFunction // error
undefinedVoidFunction = stringFunction // error

undefinedVoidFunction = undefinedFunction // no error
undefinedVoidFunction = voidFunction // no error
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4DcD2BLYAxArgHZjJYaEBc8AFFFYfgLYBGIMAlPALwB862wANwBYAFChIsBElQAHGBkZYAziALFS5KrXpNWHbnwAKCpaoA8mHDxHjw0OIhTwGLNupJlKNOi71tOXj83GFsJB2lnZWQYLEIAcw9Nbx1g-UC+aNiEsPspJ1QiUAAzOJA8Ik8tH10QjPgikFLCctsxKwqNL254eUUVNUrkwXgAelGXDHg2BRh2gSTurjT3Ia8R8cnpmFn5nEXyHqy4xLXyDYnCKZmMOdEOg8Iexubyx4utm7uxPrNBrsOyweZ0IHy+Ylc+kePWBANBYwm4NExwS0KBCxBYJ2tzELzKnSqT3R+0xCO2u1EuMIJXxaN6pgG7zJSLxLQJyR6kNWcKxFNZbxBRxiJyZmyRYjE4XyMga1Ka+IAahi4dpfFyDEF+cB4AAffg4NqiLVKklwnq-RmCsXYu7G5WEzn+GDQ618uWvYAm9lLeAo05m104ylG92K+0c5Zal2Xa42qk0tleumwh2bK7k25AA)

Answer (score 1):

For cases where you do need a `not promise` type, try the following:

```
type C<T> = (a: number) => T extends Promise<any> ? never : T;
```